# .htaccess rewrite url with string URI is number

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have a website which was built with wordpress CMS. I want to change it to another theme with custom post type.
it's current url looks like:

```
mysite.com/1234 - links for posts - 1234 is id of the post
mysite.com/topic/cate-name - is link for categories 
mysite.com/tag/tag-name - link for tags
```

now when i change to new theme and convert all post type, categories, tags, it causes some change likes:

```
mysite.com//video/1234
mysite.com/cate-vid/cat-name
mysite.com/tag-vid/tag-name
```

Please help me to rewrite my url with .htaccess for both apache and nginx serivce.
Thank you very much!